# MYSQL query optimization - how to fetch unique column from right table of join

Tags: mysql, sql

```
Person

id  |   name 
1   |   Mark 
2   |   John 
3   |   Cathy 
4   |   Susan 
5   |   Rick


Property
id  |   property_type (A,B,C,D,E,F)
1   |   A
1   |   B
1   |   C
2   |   A
2   |   A
2   |   A
3   |   C
4   |   D
4   |   E
4   |   F
4   |   A
3   |   A
5   |   A
5   |   A
```

> Query would be - Find out people's id and name who owns property of
>   only Type A. Answer should be John and Rick
>
> Right now, I am doing it this way

```
select distinct(p.id), p.name
from
  Person p
  INNER JOIN Property t
    ON p.id = t.id    
WHERE t.property_type = 'A'
    AND p.id NOT IN (
        SELECT
            id
        from
            Property
        where property_type IN (
            'B','C','D','E','F'            
        )
    )

order by p.id desc
```

Tables have hundred thousand rows and that is why I am trying to optimize this query.

I intend to fetch result in such a way that, find out people who have only type A properties.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: dude why you are using 
AND p.id NOT IN (
        SELECT
            id
        from
            Property
        where property_type IN (
            'B','C','D','E','F'            
        )
    ) 
these part..?

Comment: to skip different types properties which are owned by people. The result should be something like, people own only input type of properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation in the `having` clause:

```
select   pers.id,
         pers.name
from     person    pers
    join property  prop
      on pers.id = prop.id
group by pers.id,
         pers.name
having   sum(case when prop.property_type = 'A' then 1 else 0 end) >= 1
     and sum(case when prop.property_type <> 'A' then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

**Fiddle:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a3720/1/0

(I think you meant John and Rick)

Comment: Yes, you are right, John and Rick.. This one works but same performance. Nevertheless thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
select p.* from
Person p join 
(select id from Property 
 group by id having count(1)=1 
 and max(property_type)='A') t on p.id = t.id
```

Try this out.

I think your major problem is using `in` and `distinct` keyword

Comment: I think this won't work because max(property_type) =1 is a wrong condition, i tried to run your query on Brian's sqlfiddle it failed there as well.

Comment: @user3564816 my query is count(1)=1 and max(property_type)='A'

Comment: @user3564816 sorry for that.I just found out that your Property table have multiple rows in one id and type combination.So that's leave me no choice but use `count(distinct property_type) = 1` in `having` clause, which I think  there will be no performance inprovement

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM person p
WHERE EXISTS (  SELECT 'a'
                FROM property a
                WHERE a.id = p.id
                AND a.property_type = 'A'
              )
AND NOT EXISTS( SELECT 'b'
                FROM property b
                WHERE b.id = p.id
                AND a.property_type IN ('B','C','D','E','F')
               )
```